# Kafka Consumer Rebalancing on Spring Application Startup

Tags: spring, spring-boot, concurrency, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am experimenting on Kafka with Spring Boot.

- Spring Boot 2.1.0.RELEASE
- Spring-Kafka 2.2.0

I have a problem. If there is any unread message on topic, rebalancing of consumers is always starting on startup of my application.

I have a topic with 20 partitions, and I have 1 **KafkaListener** with concurrency of 8, and I have configured ThreadPoolTaskExecutor with:

```
@Bean
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor messageProcessorExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor exec = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        exec.setCorePoolSize(15);
        exec.setMaxPoolSize(25);
        exec.setKeepAliveSeconds(60);
        exec.setThreadNamePrefix("kafkaConsumer-");
        return exec;
    }
```

On application startup, usually only kafkaConsumer-1(sometimes kafkaConsumer-1 and kafkaConsumer-2) is starting to consuming, and for other 7 consumers I am seeing logs like below;

```
    2018-12-15 16:44:27.982  INFO 5551 --- [payment-group-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=payment-group-1] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
2018-12-15 16:44:32.050  INFO 5551 --- [payment-group-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=payment-group-1] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
2018-12-15 16:44:36.114  INFO 5551 --- [payment-group-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=payment-group-1] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
    ....
        2018-12-15 16:44:57.841  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-2] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=payment-group-1] Group coordinator 127.0.0.1:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
        2018-12-15 16:44:57.902  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-3] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=payment-group-1] Group coordinator 127.0.0.1:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
        2018-12-15 16:44:57.956  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-2] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=payment-group-1] Discovered group coordinator 127.0.0.1:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null)
        2018-12-15 16:44:57.956  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-2] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=payment-group-1] (Re-)joining group
        2018-12-15 16:44:57.999  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-4] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-5, groupId=payment-group-1] Group coordinator 127.0.0.1:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
        2018-12-15 16:44:58.016  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-3] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=payment-group-1] Discovered group coordinator 127.0.0.1:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null)
        2018-12-15 16:44:58.017  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-3] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=payment-group-1] (Re-)joining group
        2018-12-15 16:44:58.056  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-5] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-6, groupId=payment-group-1] Group coordinator 127.0.0.1:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
        2018-12-15 16:44:58.064  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-6] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-7, groupId=payment-group-1] Group coordinator 127.0.0.1:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
        2018-12-15 16:44:58.072  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-7] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-8, groupId=payment-group-1] Group coordinator 127.0.0.1:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
        2018-12-15 16:44:58.085  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-8] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-9, groupId=payment-group-1] Group coordinator 127.0.0.1:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
        2018-12-15 16:44:58.114  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-4] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-5, groupId=payment-group-1] Discovered group coordinator 127.0.0.1:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null)
        2018-12-15 16:44:58.114  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-4] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-5, groupId=payment-group-1] (Re-)joining group
        2018-12-15 16:44:58.170  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-5] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-6, groupId=payment-group-1] Discovered group coordinator 127.0.0.1:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null)
        2018-12-15 16:44:58.171  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-5] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-6, groupId=payment-group-1] (Re-)joining group
        2018-12-15 16:44:58.185  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-6] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-7, groupId=payment-group-1] Discovered group coordinator 127.0.0.1:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null)
        2018-12-15 16:44:58.186  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-6] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-7, groupId=payment-group-1] (Re-)joining group
        2018-12-15 16:44:58.191  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-7] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-8, groupId=payment-group-1] Discovered group coordinator 127.0.0.1:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null)
        2018-12-15 16:44:58.191  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-7] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-8, groupId=payment-group-1] (Re-)joining group
        2018-12-15 16:44:58.201  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-8] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-9, groupId=payment-group-1] Discovered group coordinator 127.0.0.1:9092 (id: 2147483646 rack: null)
        2018-12-15 16:44:58.202  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-8] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-9, groupId=payment-group-1] (Re-)joining group
```

And while consumption by one thread I am seeing below:

```
    bash-4.4# $KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group payment-group-1 --describe
Warning: Consumer group 'payment-group-1' is rebalancing.
```

And after consumption of existing messages is finished, rebalancing is also being completed, and I am seeing logs like below;

```
    2018-12-15 16:46:12.415  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=payment-group-1] Revoking previously assigned partitions [TopicY-4, TopicY-5, TopicY-6, TopicY-7, TopicY-8, TopicY-9, TopicY-10, TopicY-11, TopicY-0, TopicY-1, TopicY-2, TopicY-3, TopicY-12, TopicY-13, TopicY-14, TopicY-15, TopicY-16, TopicY-17, TopicY-18, TopicY-19]
2018-12-15 16:46:12.415  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions revoked: [TopicY-4, TopicY-5, TopicY-6, TopicY-7, TopicY-8, TopicY-9, TopicY-10, TopicY-11, TopicY-0, TopicY-1, TopicY-2, TopicY-3, TopicY-12, TopicY-13, TopicY-14, TopicY-15, TopicY-16, TopicY-17, TopicY-18, TopicY-19]
2018-12-15 16:46:12.415  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=payment-group-1] (Re-)joining group
2018-12-15 16:46:12.482  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-6] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-7, groupId=payment-group-1] Successfully joined group with generation 25
2018-12-15 16:46:12.482  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-3] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=payment-group-1] Successfully joined group with generation 25
2018-12-15 16:46:12.482  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-7] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-8, groupId=payment-group-1] Successfully joined group with generation 25
2018-12-15 16:46:12.483  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-7] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-8, groupId=payment-group-1] Setting newly assigned partitions []
2018-12-15 16:46:12.483  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-7] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: []
2018-12-15 16:46:12.484  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-4] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-5, groupId=payment-group-1] Successfully joined group with generation 25
2018-12-15 16:46:12.484  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-4] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-5, groupId=payment-group-1] Setting newly assigned partitions [TopicY-11]
2018-12-15 16:46:12.485  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-8] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-9, groupId=payment-group-1] Successfully joined group with generation 25
2018-12-15 16:46:12.485  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-8] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-9, groupId=payment-group-1] Setting newly assigned partitions []
2018-12-15 16:46:12.485  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-8] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: []
2018-12-15 16:46:12.486  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-2] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=payment-group-1] Successfully joined group with generation 25
2018-12-15 16:46:12.486  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-5] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-6, groupId=payment-group-1] Successfully joined group with generation 25
2018-12-15 16:46:12.486  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-5] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-6, groupId=payment-group-1] Setting newly assigned partitions [TopicY-15]
2018-12-15 16:46:12.486  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-2] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=payment-group-1] Setting newly assigned partitions [TopicY-3]
2018-12-15 16:46:12.487  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-3] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=payment-group-1] Setting newly assigned partitions [TopicY-5]
2018-12-15 16:46:12.489  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-6] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-7, groupId=payment-group-1] Setting newly assigned partitions [TopicY-19]
2018-12-15 16:46:12.489  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=payment-group-1] Successfully joined group with generation 25
2018-12-15 16:46:12.497  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=payment-group-1] Setting newly assigned partitions [TopicY-0]
2018-12-15 16:46:12.509  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-3] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [TopicY-5]
2018-12-15 16:46:12.514  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-6] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [TopicY-19]
2018-12-15 16:46:12.517  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [TopicY-0]
2018-12-15 16:46:12.611  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-2] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [TopicY-3]
2018-12-15 16:46:12.612  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-5] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [TopicY-15]
2018-12-15 16:46:12.628  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-4] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [TopicY-11]
2018-12-15 16:47:44.563  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-4] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-5, groupId=payment-group-1] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
2018-12-15 16:47:44.564  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-4] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-5, groupId=payment-group-1] Revoking previously assigned partitions [TopicY-11]
2018-12-15 16:47:44.564  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-4] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions revoked: [TopicY-11]
2018-12-15 16:47:44.564  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-4] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-5, groupId=payment-group-1] (Re-)joining group
2018-12-15 16:47:44.577  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-5] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-6, groupId=payment-group-1] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
2018-12-15 16:47:44.577  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-2] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=payment-group-1] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
2018-12-15 16:47:44.577  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-5] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-6, groupId=payment-group-1] Revoking previously assigned partitions [TopicY-15]
2018-12-15 16:47:44.577  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-2] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=payment-group-1] Revoking previously assigned partitions [TopicY-3]
2018-12-15 16:47:44.577  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-5] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions revoked: [TopicY-15]
2018-12-15 16:47:44.577  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-2] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions revoked: [TopicY-3]
2018-12-15 16:47:44.577  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-5] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-6, groupId=payment-group-1] (Re-)joining group
2018-12-15 16:47:44.577  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-2] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=payment-group-1] (Re-)joining group
2018-12-15 16:47:44.577  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-7] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-8, groupId=payment-group-1] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
2018-12-15 16:47:44.577  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-7] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-8, groupId=payment-group-1] Revoking previously assigned partitions []
2018-12-15 16:47:44.578  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-7] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions revoked: []
2018-12-15 16:47:44.578  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-7] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-8, groupId=payment-group-1] (Re-)joining group
2018-12-15 16:47:44.586  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-3] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=payment-group-1] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
2018-12-15 16:47:44.587  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-6] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-7, groupId=payment-group-1] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
2018-12-15 16:47:44.587  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-3] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=payment-group-1] Revoking previously assigned partitions [TopicY-5]
2018-12-15 16:47:44.587  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-6] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-7, groupId=payment-group-1] Revoking previously assigned partitions [TopicY-19]
2018-12-15 16:47:44.587  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-3] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions revoked: [TopicY-5]
2018-12-15 16:47:44.587  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-6] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions revoked: [TopicY-19]
2018-12-15 16:47:44.587  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-3] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=payment-group-1] (Re-)joining group
2018-12-15 16:47:44.587  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-6] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-7, groupId=payment-group-1] (Re-)joining group
2018-12-15 16:47:44.589  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-8] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-9, groupId=payment-group-1] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
2018-12-15 16:47:44.589  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=payment-group-1] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
2018-12-15 16:47:44.589  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-8] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-9, groupId=payment-group-1] Revoking previously assigned partitions []
2018-12-15 16:47:44.589  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-8] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions revoked: []
2018-12-15 16:47:44.589  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=payment-group-1] Revoking previously assigned partitions [TopicY-0]
2018-12-15 16:47:44.589  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions revoked: [TopicY-0]
2018-12-15 16:47:44.589  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=payment-group-1] (Re-)joining group
2018-12-15 16:47:44.589  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-8] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-9, groupId=payment-group-1] (Re-)joining group
2018-12-15 16:47:44.602  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-3] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=payment-group-1] Successfully joined group with generation 26
2018-12-15 16:47:44.602  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-6] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-7, groupId=payment-group-1] Successfully joined group with generation 26
2018-12-15 16:47:44.603  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-3] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=payment-group-1] Setting newly assigned partitions [TopicY-6, TopicY-7, TopicY-8]
2018-12-15 16:47:44.603  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-6] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-7, groupId=payment-group-1] Setting newly assigned partitions [TopicY-14, TopicY-15]
2018-12-15 16:47:44.603  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=payment-group-1] Successfully joined group with generation 26
2018-12-15 16:47:44.604  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=payment-group-1] Setting newly assigned partitions [TopicY-0, TopicY-1, TopicY-2]
2018-12-15 16:47:44.604  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-7] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-8, groupId=payment-group-1] Successfully joined group with generation 26
2018-12-15 16:47:44.605  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-7] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-8, groupId=payment-group-1] Setting newly assigned partitions [TopicY-16, TopicY-17]
2018-12-15 16:47:44.606  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-2] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=payment-group-1] Successfully joined group with generation 26
2018-12-15 16:47:44.606  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-2] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=payment-group-1] Setting newly assigned partitions [TopicY-4, TopicY-5, TopicY-3]
2018-12-15 16:47:44.610  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-4] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-5, groupId=payment-group-1] Successfully joined group with generation 26
2018-12-15 16:47:44.610  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-5] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-6, groupId=payment-group-1] Successfully joined group with generation 26
2018-12-15 16:47:44.611  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-4] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-5, groupId=payment-group-1] Setting newly assigned partitions [TopicY-9, TopicY-10, TopicY-11]
2018-12-15 16:47:44.611  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-5] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-6, groupId=payment-group-1] Setting newly assigned partitions [TopicY-12, TopicY-13]
2018-12-15 16:47:44.612  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-8] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-9, groupId=payment-group-1] Successfully joined group with generation 26
2018-12-15 16:47:44.612  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-8] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-9, groupId=payment-group-1] Setting newly assigned partitions [TopicY-18, TopicY-19]
2018-12-15 16:47:44.612  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-6] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [TopicY-14, TopicY-15]
2018-12-15 16:47:44.614  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-3] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [TopicY-6, TopicY-7, TopicY-8]
2018-12-15 16:47:44.618  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [TopicY-0, TopicY-1, TopicY-2]
2018-12-15 16:47:44.623  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-7] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [TopicY-16, TopicY-17]
2018-12-15 16:47:44.625  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-2] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [TopicY-4, TopicY-5, TopicY-3]
2018-12-15 16:47:44.626  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-8] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [TopicY-18, TopicY-19]
2018-12-15 16:47:44.628  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-5] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [TopicY-12, TopicY-13]
2018-12-15 16:47:44.877  INFO 5551 --- [kafkaConsumer-4] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [TopicY-9, TopicY-10, TopicY-11]
```

I want to use Kafka in application with minimum 100 tps. But, I am struggled with my experiments about the test case I mentioned. Rebalancing takes too long, and usually I am consuming all messages with one thread. I am not able to consume all messages with one thread on production.

**Notes:**

1. I am writing consumers with **@KafkaListener** annotation.
2. I have tried many kind of consumer configs.

My current config is:

```
ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG=false
SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG=90000
HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG=4000
AckMode=AckMode.RECORD
PollTimeout=10000
```

I am asking any advice to solve my problem.

Btw, If there is no unread message on topic, rebalancing does not occur, and I am immediately seeing logs like below;

```
    2018-12-15 17:12:01.618  INFO 5559 --- [kafkaConsumer-8] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-9, groupId=payment-group-1] (Re-)joining group
2018-12-15 17:12:01.676  INFO 5559 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''
2018-12-15 17:12:01.684  INFO 5559 --- [           main] o.e.k.KafkaListenerApplication           : Started KafkaListenerApplication in 7.099 seconds (JVM running for 9.026)
2018-12-15 17:12:05.363  INFO 5559 --- [kafkaConsumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=payment-group-1] Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing
2018-12-15 17:12:05.364  INFO 5559 --- [kafkaConsumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=payment-group-1] Revoking previously assigned partitions [TopicY-4, TopicY-5, TopicY-6, TopicY-7, TopicY-8, TopicY-9, TopicY-10, TopicY-11, TopicY-0, TopicY-1, TopicY-2, TopicY-3, TopicY-12, TopicY-13, TopicY-14, TopicY-15, TopicY-16, TopicY-17, TopicY-18, TopicY-19]
2018-12-15 17:12:05.364  INFO 5559 --- [kafkaConsumer-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions revoked: [TopicY-4, TopicY-5, TopicY-6, TopicY-7, TopicY-8, TopicY-9, TopicY-10, TopicY-11, TopicY-0, TopicY-1, TopicY-2, TopicY-3, TopicY-12, TopicY-13, TopicY-14, TopicY-15, TopicY-16, TopicY-17, TopicY-18, TopicY-19]
2018-12-15 17:12:05.364  INFO 5559 --- [kafkaConsumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=payment-group-1] (Re-)joining group
2018-12-15 17:12:05.382  INFO 5559 --- [kafkaConsumer-5] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-6, groupId=payment-group-1] Successfully joined group with generation 29
2018-12-15 17:12:05.382  INFO 5559 --- [kafkaConsumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=payment-group-1] Successfully joined group with generation 29
2018-12-15 17:12:05.382  INFO 5559 --- [kafkaConsumer-5] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-6, groupId=payment-group-1] Setting newly assigned partitions [TopicY-12, TopicY-13]
2018-12-15 17:12:05.384  INFO 5559 --- [kafkaConsumer-2] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=payment-group-1] Successfully joined group with generation 29
2018-12-15 17:12:05.384  INFO 5559 --- [kafkaConsumer-7] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-8, groupId=payment-group-1] Successfully joined group with generation 29
2018-12-15 17:12:05.384  INFO 5559 --- [kafkaConsumer-2] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-3, groupId=payment-group-1] Setting newly assigned partitions [TopicY-4, TopicY-5, TopicY-3]
2018-12-15 17:12:05.384  INFO 5559 --- [kafkaConsumer-7] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-8, groupId=payment-group-1] Setting newly assigned partitions [TopicY-16, TopicY-17]
2018-12-15 17:12:05.385  INFO 5559 --- [kafkaConsumer-4] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-5, groupId=payment-group-1] Successfully joined group with generation 29
2018-12-15 17:12:05.385  INFO 5559 --- [kafkaConsumer-3] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=payment-group-1] Successfully joined group with generation 29
2018-12-15 17:12:05.385  INFO 5559 --- [kafkaConsumer-4] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-5, groupId=payment-group-1] Setting newly assigned partitions [TopicY-9, TopicY-10, TopicY-11]
2018-12-15 17:12:05.385  INFO 5559 --- [kafkaConsumer-8] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-9, groupId=payment-group-1] Successfully joined group with generation 29
2018-12-15 17:12:05.385  INFO 5559 --- [kafkaConsumer-3] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=payment-group-1] Setting newly assigned partitions [TopicY-6, TopicY-7, TopicY-8]
2018-12-15 17:12:05.385  INFO 5559 --- [kafkaConsumer-8] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-9, groupId=payment-group-1] Setting newly assigned partitions [TopicY-18, TopicY-19]
2018-12-15 17:12:05.385  INFO 5559 --- [kafkaConsumer-6] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-7, groupId=payment-group-1] Successfully joined group with generation 29
2018-12-15 17:12:05.386  INFO 5559 --- [kafkaConsumer-6] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-7, groupId=payment-group-1] Setting newly assigned partitions [TopicY-14, TopicY-15]
2018-12-15 17:12:05.389  INFO 5559 --- [kafkaConsumer-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=payment-group-1] Setting newly assigned partitions [TopicY-0, TopicY-1, TopicY-2]
2018-12-15 17:12:05.400  INFO 5559 --- [kafkaConsumer-4] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [TopicY-9, TopicY-10, TopicY-11]
2018-12-15 17:12:05.404  INFO 5559 --- [kafkaConsumer-8] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [TopicY-18, TopicY-19]
2018-12-15 17:12:05.404  INFO 5559 --- [kafkaConsumer-6] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [TopicY-14, TopicY-15]
2018-12-15 17:12:05.410  INFO 5559 --- [kafkaConsumer-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [TopicY-0, TopicY-1, TopicY-2]
2018-12-15 17:12:05.505  INFO 5559 --- [kafkaConsumer-7] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [TopicY-16, TopicY-17]
2018-12-15 17:12:05.510  INFO 5559 --- [kafkaConsumer-3] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [TopicY-6, TopicY-7, TopicY-8]
2018-12-15 17:12:05.516  INFO 5559 --- [kafkaConsumer-2] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [TopicY-4, TopicY-5, TopicY-3]
2018-12-15 17:12:05.520  INFO 5559 --- [kafkaConsumer-5] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : partitions assigned: [TopicY-12, TopicY-13]
```

Comment: Have u tried this without spring-kafka?

Comment: @Sammy do you mean for example Spring Integration ? If yes, I haven't tried it.

Comment: As the new threads are starting, it'll naturally rebalance until all are up, unless you manually set each thread to a partition manually.

Comment: @cricket_007 okey but, how can I decrease time for getting all threads are up. It is too long in my local development environment. I am keeping listener busy in each consumption for 3sec without Thread.sleep(3000L) Sometimes rebalancing never finishes until many messages are consumed by one thread(For example; 100 messages x 3 sec = 300 sec). I am playing with some timeout configs, but I am not sure which one is relevant in my situation.

Comment: In general, I scale my jobs over different machines / Docker containers. I haven't used ThreadPools in Spring-Kafka. I'm just pointing out, that is why you see the rebalancing

Comment: As I mentioned, though, you might be able to take the Thread ID and `assign()` it to the `KafkaConsumer` to designate which Thread goes to which partition, rather than have it be randomly assigned, and rebalanced as new threads become available. (I don't have example code of this, though)

Comment: @cricket_007 I have already assigned taskexecutor to KafkaListenerContainerFactory bean. factory.getContainerProperties().setConsumerTaskExecutor(messageProcessorExecutor());

Comment: Well, I don't know Spring, but that wasn't what I was saying. If you search the [JavaDoc](https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html) for "manual partition assignment", that is what I was referring to